# Listview with images & checkboxes restrict the user to select 5 checkboxes only

Tags: android

I had listview with images and checkboxes wher i have to restrict the user to check 5 checkboxes and disable or make invisible other checkboxes in the list view and whenever user uncheck's one of the five checkboxes that was previous checked should make checkbox enabled or visible again.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by counter variable as you have to check for all the check box status using iterator also or you can put in click event of checkbox to check whether it reached to limit or not if it reached already after checked the 5th one then disable the another checkbox and when it less then then enable it reset of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to prevent the user from selecting more than 5 - meaning they have to manually uncheck items - just use a counter variable like pratik suggested. If you want to automatically uncheck the oldest thing the user checked, I would use a queue of the selected indexes. then you can pop the oldest thing off, uncheck it, and add the new index to the queue. you could do all of this in an onItemClickListener or onItemSelectedListener

Comment: I'm trying to do it using onsetcheckedchangedListener in getview method.Now i'm able to check checkboxes and capture the ids of checkboxes but i want to restrict them for 5 and set visibility gone for all checkboxes that aren't selected.

Comment: do what pratik said and keep a counter for the number of items checked. when it hits five, don't allow the view to be checked. i think it would be easier to use the onItemClick to handle it but...

Answer (score 0):

You can use onCheckedChangeListener.

Add a private integer:

```
private int checkedCounter;
```

Initialize it:

```
checkedCounter = 0;
```

Set listener:

```
yourCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.itsId);
yourCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {   
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
        {
            if (checkedCounter == 5 && isChecked)
            {
                yourCheckbox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else if checkedCounter == 5 && !isChecked)
            {
                checkedCounter--;
            }
            else if (checkedCounter < 5)
            {
                (isChecked ? checkedCounter++ : checkedCounter--);
            }
        }
    });
```

I can't run this code right now so check the conditions.
Actually it can be done also in another way: When 5 boxes are checked you can use setEnabled(false) method on others.